# Why does the label never show up in my UITableViewCell subclass?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

Example project: http://cl.ly/283O3a0x2l3h

I'm trying to create a custom cell with some views in it, so I subclassed `UITableViewCell` as shown below. That subclass has a UILabel that gets created on `init` and positioned in `updateConstraints`.

However, whenever I run the app, it never shows the label on the cells. In fact, the init method for the UITableViewCell subclass is never end called.

This is called in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
cell.postTitle.text = @"testing";
```

However `initWithStyle:` in the UITableViewCell subclass is never once called, and I can't figure out why. It's worth noting that it has a bit done from Interface Builder, but just the UITableView set up with the cell deemed to be a subclass of UITableViewCell.

Can anyone take a look and tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Update your post with the relevant code. Include your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and maybe the `init` method of your custom cell class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to do it programmatically, use `initWithCoder`. Even easier, create `IBOutlet` references in you cell prototype, and you can eliminate all of that code which is creating it programmatically altogether. Just define your outlets and constraints in code, and then you can retire all of that code inside the `CSPostCell` implementation:

[image: outlets for table view cell]

So you enjoy the benefits of the `CSPostCell` subclass, but without any of the code.

Comment: How come the GitHub example I posted is using `initWithStyle` though and it does it programmatically? And while I considered doing it with IB, the cell layout is rather dynamic (might include thumbnails, optional labels depending on the type of content it's displaying, etc.) so I felt doing it all in code would be the best way. Would you agree?

Comment: @DougSmith Why was it using `initWithStyle`? That's the technique that predates cell prototypes. If you're going to use the cell prototype, that's instantiated with `initWithCoder`. If you just want to do it programmatically you can eliminate the cell prototype, stay with `initWithStyle`, but your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` would have to check to see `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` returned `nil`, and if so, then manually call `initWithStyle`, like we used to do in olden days.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to load up a custom cell from a NIB file.  The custom tableView cell (FileTableViewCell) is created in IB and contains two labels, a progress bar, a button and sometimes an activity indicator gets added to the accessoryView.  So try just replacing the `cell = [nib...` line with `cell = [YourSubClass...]` and then modify the rest as required by your app.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FileTableViewCell";
    //LOG(@" tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:");
    FileTableViewCell *cell = (FileTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        //LOG(@" cell is nil so create one");
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FileTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        //FLOG(@" nib is %@", nib);
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    // Configure the cell.
    FileRepresentation* fileRepresentation = _fileList[indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self userFilename:[fileRepresentation.fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [fileRepresentation modifiedDate];

    float percentage = [fileRepresentation.percentDownloaded intValue] / 100.0;
    int ds = [self downloadStatus:fileRepresentation];


    if (ds == 1) {
        //FLOG(@" download process for file is %f", percentage);
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UIActivityIndicatorView *progressView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.accessoryView = progressView;
        [cell.progressIndicator setHidden:NO];
        [cell.progressIndicator setProgress:percentage];
        [progressView startAnimating];
    }
    if (ds == 2) {
        //FLOG(@" download process for file is %f", percentage);
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        UIActivityIndicatorView *progressView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        cell.accessoryView = progressView;
        [cell.progressIndicator setHidden:NO];
        [cell.progressIndicator setProgress:percentage];
        [progressView startAnimating];
    }
    if (ds == 3) {
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.accessoryView=nil;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        [cell.progressIndicator setHidden:YES];

    }
    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_fileImageName];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the instance of your custom `UITableViewCell` subclass is loaded at runtime, its `initWithCoder:` method is called instead of the `initWithStyle:` method. (You would call `initWithStyle:` if you created a new instance with `alloc`, but that's not the case here.) To fix the problem, simply change the method signature accordingly.

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self == nil) return nil;

    // Initialization code goes here...

    return self;
}
```

For more insight into how objects are deserialized from nib files and storyboards, see the [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html)